# Deleting Clash of Clans account with TH 7

Tags: clash-of-clans

I started playing many years ago on my iPad and now I have a towhnhall 10 level 116. Recently I got a new phone and I installed Clash of Clans on it, and started levelling it up. It is now a townhall 7. 
Recently I have gotten alot more serious on my main account trying to push for trophies.

So I wanted to delete my townhall 7 user, and link my main account to that device. Unfortunately that is not possible because you can't delete / remove a user with a townhall 4 or higher.

I am logged in with the same Apple-ID on both devices.

Answer (score 1):

Contact SuperCell support from within the app and explain your issue. 
Alternatively, you could open another Google play account with a different (real) phone number and email address and link the TH7 to that, then ask in the in game help to have them disconnect your TH7 from the original device because you want a different account on that device. I went through that process and they severed the link with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the app on your TH7 account and redownload it. Sign into your account and hopefully you can choose the first account - you can't obviously delete the TH7 account but you'll be logged out.